# d3 gauge chart with labels and percentages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, charts

We're searching for a radial chart that looks like the following. What's most interesting about this chart is that it has the percentage. We've been searching for about three days and we haven't found anything that uses the `d3.js` library.

We found these two solid gauge charts, one from [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/solid-gauge/) and the other from [anycharts](http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/Circular_Gauges/Solid_Gauge.php), but neither have the percentage as clear. [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity) also has something similar, but not labels. Plus, they don't use d3 and not open-source.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Interesting but off topic as it is a "please recommend me a resource" question.

Comment: It's not a "please recommend me a resource" question since I'm not asking for a recommendation. I'm looking for something that I have not found.

Comment: I wish you every success in your quest.

Comment: [This Highcharts demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/gauge-activity/) is fairly simple to adapt to give [nearly what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/nLz3e9ko/). As you will see, I retained the demo's tooltip appraoch to displaying values; I didn't attempt the question's arced "xx%" labels, though I see @bumbeishvili has cleverly mastered that aspect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be easily coded from scratch

It's possible to get coordinate of segment's end or start, using `centroid` function,  after that you can add text here and rotate it accordingly

```js
var data = [45,33,66,50,90]

var svg = d3.select('#result').append('svg').attr('width',500).attr('height',500)



var arcs = data.map((v,i)=>{
    return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i*20+60).outerRadius((i+1)*20-5+60)
});


var pieData = data.map((v,i)=>{
   return [{value:v*0.75,arc:arcs[i]},{value:(100-v)*0.75,arc:arcs[i]},{value:100*0.25,arc:arcs[i]}]
})


var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(d=>d.value)
    
    
  var g = svg.selectAll('g').data(pieData).enter().append('g').attr('transform','translate(250,250) rotate(180)').attr('fill-opacity',(d,i)=>2/(i+1))
 
 // progress
 g.selectAll('path').data(d=>{return pie(d)}).enter().append('path').attr('d',d=>{return d.data.arc(d)})
 .attr('fill',(d,i)=>i==0?'blue':'none')
 
svg.selectAll('g').each(function(d){
var el = d3.select(this);
  el.selectAll('path').each((r,i)=>{
    
    if(i==1){
    var centroid = r.data.arc.centroid({startAngle:r.startAngle+0.05,endAngle:r.startAngle+0.001+0.05})
    g.append('text').text(100-Math.floor(r.value)+'%').attr('transform',`translate(${centroid[0]},${centroid[1]}) rotate(${180/Math.PI*(r.startAngle)+7})`).attr('alignment-baseline','middle')
    }

  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I have also need to this type chart.

My code is as following this make responsive graph according to parent width. 
for it you need to get parent width and assign it to `var width` variable

Hope this code help you.

```js
var width = 300;
                var arcSize = (6 * width / 100);
                var innerRadius = arcSize * 3;            

                var data = [
                    {value: 45, label: "label_1", color: '#ff0000'},
                    {value: 33, label: "label_2", color: '#00ff00'},
                    {value: 66, label: "label_3", color: '#0000ff'},
                    {value: 50, label: "label_4", color: '#ffff00'},
                    {value: 90, label: "label_5", color: '#ff0099'}
                ];
  
                function render() {
                    var svg = d3.select('#result').append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', width);

                    var arcs = data.map(function (obj, i) {
                        return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i * arcSize + innerRadius).outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - (width / 100) + innerRadius);
                    });
                    var arcsGrey = data.map(function (obj, i) {
                        return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i * arcSize + (innerRadius + ((arcSize / 2) - 2))).outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - ((arcSize / 2)) + (innerRadius));
                    });

                    var pieData = data.map(function (obj, i) {
                        return [
                            {value: obj.value * 0.75, arc: arcs[i], object: obj},
                            {value: (100 - obj.value) * 0.75, arc: arcsGrey[i], object: obj},
                            {value: 100 * 0.25, arc: arcs[i], object: obj}];
                    });

                    var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function (d) {
                        return d.value;
                    });

                    var g = svg.selectAll('g').data(pieData).enter()
                        .append('g')
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + width / 2 + ') rotate(180)');
                    var gText = svg.selectAll('g.textClass').data([{}]).enter()
                        .append('g')
                        .classed('textClass', true)
                        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + width / 2 + ') rotate(180)');


                    g.selectAll('path').data(function (d) {
                        return pie(d);
                    }).enter().append('path')
                        .attr('id', function (d, i) {
                            if (i == 1) {
                                return "Text" + d.data.object.label
                            }
                        })
                        .attr('d', function (d) {
                            return d.data.arc(d);
                        }).attr('fill', function (d, i) {
                        return i == 0 ? d.data.object.color : i == 1 ? '#D3D3D3' : 'none';
                    });

                    svg.selectAll('g').each(function (d, index) {
                        var el = d3.select(this);
                        var path = el.selectAll('path').each(function (r, i) {
                            if (i === 1) {
                                var centroid = r.data.arc.centroid({
                                    startAngle: r.startAngle + 0.05,
                                    endAngle: r.startAngle + 0.001 + 0.05
                                });
                                var lableObj = r.data.object;
                                g.append('text')
                                    .attr('font-size', ((5 * width) / 100))
                                    .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
                                    /*.attr('transform', "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + (centroid[1] + 10) + ") rotate(" + (180 / Math.PI * r.startAngle + 7) + ")")
                                     .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')*/
                                    .append("textPath")
                                    .attr("textLength", function (d, i) {
                                        return 0;
                                    })
                                    .attr("xlink:href", "#Text" + r.data.object.label)
                                    .attr("startOffset", '5')
                                    .attr("dy", '-3em')
                                    .text(lableObj.value + '%');
                            }
                            if (i === 0) {
                                var centroidText = r.data.arc.centroid({
                                    startAngle: r.startAngle,
                                    endAngle: r.startAngle
                                });
                                var lableObj = r.data.object;
                                gText.append('text')
                                    .attr('font-size', ((5 * width) / 100))
                                    .text(lableObj.label)
                                    .attr('transform', "translate(" + (centroidText[0] - ((1.5 * width) / 100)) + "," + (centroidText[1] + ") rotate(" + (180) + ")"))
                                    .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }

          
                render()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome!  I just got a request for a chart like this!  You save me a lot of work  Much thanks.